# Convert JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> to JavaPairDStream<Integer, String>, switching values in tuple (Java Spark)

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I thought I could just do

```
final JavaPairDstream<String, Integer> y = ... ;

final JavaPairDStream<Integer, String> x =
                    y.mapToPair(item -> {
        return new JavaPairDStream<Integer, String>(item[1], item[0]);
    });
```

But it gives me the error:

```
array required, but scala.Tuple2<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer> found
```

How can I switch the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is returning the wrong type. It's `mapToPair` that returns a `JavaPairDStream<Integer, String>`, your function returns `Tuple2<Integer, String>` objects that make the stream.

So your statement should be:

```
final JavaPairDStream<Integer, String> x = 
             y.mapToPair(item -> new Tuple2<>(item._2, item._1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can also do

```
JavaPairDStream<Integer,String> swappedPair = wordCounts.mapToPair(x -> x.swap());
```